# call method from custom cell in iphone application

Tags: iphone, uibutton, custom-cell

i have one view controller
Name : FirstVC

i have table view in that view controller. in my table view i load a custom cell. in my custom cell there is 1 label and 1 button. i set label as well as button of custom cell from FirstVC. See bellow code.

in FirstVC.h

```
@interface FirstVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *TblView;
    IBOutlet CustomCell *customCell;
}
- (void)addCounter:(NSInteger)pCat_ID;

@end
```

in FirstVC.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell = categoryCustomCell;
        }
NSInteger pCat_id = [[[arrayCategoryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cat_id"] integerValue];
        [customCell setTextForLable:@"Test"];
        [customCell setAddCounterButton:pCat_id];

        return cell;
}

- (void)addCounter:(NSInteger)pCat_ID
{
    //Some code here….
}
```

in CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblCategoryName;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnAddCounter;
}

- (void)setTextForLable:(NSString *)cat_name;
- (void)setAddCounterButton:(NSInteger)cat_ID;

@end
```

in CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (void)setTextForLable:(NSString *)cat_name
{
    lblCategoryName.text = cat_name;
}

- (void)setAddCounterButton:(NSInteger)cat_ID
{
    [btnAddCounter addTarget:self action:@selector(addCounter:cat_ID) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

@end
```

i want to call **addCounter:(NSInteger)pCat_ID** method from custom cell. but this idea can not worked. Please suggest me new idea.

Comment: What is the use of cat_ID? and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell = categoryCustomCell;
    } 
     NSInteger pCat_id = [[[arrayCategoryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
    // call your method from here.. and put your method in this file then it will work for you
 [cell.btnAddCounter addTarget:self action:@selector(addCounter:pCat_id) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
```

}

Comment: Correct according to me just pass index path in selector so that you can get row on which button was clicked